# Is GLSL buffer qualifier only available for OpenGL 4.3 and later

Tags: opengl, glsl, shader

Well, the title asks my question. I read [this wiki page](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Type_Qualifier_(GLSL)#Buffer) and get disappointed. So, for older versions of OpenGL, there is no way to use `buffer` qualifier, right?

EDIT:

I need `buffer` qualifier very badly to transfer some data from GPU to CPU

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Shader Storage buffer objects](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Shader_Storage_Buffer_Object) are available, if the [ARB_shader_storage_buffer_object](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/extensions/ARB/ARB_shader_storage_buffer_object.txt) extension is available or since OpenGL Version 4.3.

See [OpenGL 4.3 core specification; F.2 New Features; page 644](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/glspec43.core.pdf):

> New features in OpenGL 4.3, including the extension or extensions if any on which
> they were based, include:
>
> - [...]
> - ARB_shader_storage_buffer_object

See [ARB_shader_storage_buffer_object](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/extensions/ARB/ARB_shader_storage_buffer_object.txt):

> Including the following line in a shader can be used to control the language features described in this extension:
>
> ```
>  #extension GL_ARB_shader_storage_buffer_object : enable
> ```