# Send data from OpenGL shader to CPU memory

Tags: c++, opengl-es, glsl, opengl-es-2.0

I'm highlighting every pixel on my 3D objects with red color, if the dot-product of my mesh triangle normal with vector `(0, 0, -1)` is larger than `0.73`. It means, if my mesh triangle has a slope larger than a certain value:

[image: Teapot highlighted]

I'm using a fragment/pixel shader like this:

```
#define FP highp

varying FP vec3 worldNormal; // comes from vertex shader

void main()
{
    vec3 n = normalize(worldNormal);
    vec3 z = vec3(0.0, 0.0, -1.0); // Normalized already
    float zDotN = dot(z, n); // Dot-product of "n" and "z"

    if ( zDotN > 0.73 ) {
        vec3 oc = vec3(1.0, 1.0-zDotN, 1.0-zDotN); // Color: shades of red!
        gl_FragColor = vec4(oc, 1.0);
    } else {
        gl_FragColor = vec4( /* Compute color according to Phong material */ );
    }

}
```

I need to be compatible with older versions of OpenGL and OpenGL **ES 2.0** for embedded devices.

---

My problem is: I need to have access to vertex coordinates (of mesh triangles) of the highlighted areas from within my C++ code. One option might be to use [SSBO](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Shader_Storage_Buffer_Object) but they are [not available](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54287432/3405291) for older versions of OpenGL. Can anybody introduce an approach or workaround?

Comment: Possibly you can use [Transform Feedback](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Transform_Feedback), which might be is available in OpenGL 2.0, by the extension [ARB_transform_feedback2](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/extensions/ARB/ARB_transform_feedback2.txt). But I've no idea if it is available in OpenGL ES 2.0.

Comment: @Rabbid76 Is it possible to solve my problem with [Atomic Counter](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Atomic_Counter)? I wonder whether my problem is too complex to be solved with `Atomic Counter`!

Comment: Don't think I've seen any mobile implementations of transform feedback extensions for OpenGL ES 2.0, although it is a standard in ES 3.0 onwards. Atomics are not available in ES 2.0 either.

Comment: Workaround -> process the vertices in software on the CPU. Assuming you control the content, and know the vertex transform, you can do it quite efficiently on ARM e.g. with NEON SIMD.

Comment: @solidpixel Right. I have access to mesh primitive triangles and mesh transformations on CPU. I'm going to do the process on CPU with C++. Thanks =)